# Significance test to compare joint probabilities

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, copula

I have a dataset $A$ that is a time series of two variables $X$ and $Y$ (let's say these represent temperature and precipitation). I am calculating the probability of joint exceedances $X$>$x_1$ & $Y$>$y_1$, being $x_1$ and $y_1$ fixed threshold (e.g 30 and 3 respectively). I am using two approaches:

1. using simple frequency counting (e.g.):

- $P_{A}$($X$>$x_1$, $Y$>$y_1$)=(sum($X$>$x_1$ & $Y$>$y_1$)/n
  #n=total number of observations

2. using copula to get the joint distribution and compute the probability (e.g.)

- $P_{A}$($X$>$x_1$, $Y$>$y_1$) = 1 - $F_x$ - $F_y$ + pCopula(c($F_x$,$F_y$), tCopula(0.6))

Where $F_x$ and $F_y$ are the marginals that can be assumed to be normal:

```r
     Fx <- pnorm(x1, mean(X), sd(X))
     Fy <- pnorm(y1, mean(Y), sd(Y))
```

Now, let's say I have another dataset $B$, which is also a time series of $X$ (temperature) and $Y$(precipitation), but independent from $A$ (e.g. different dates). I calculated the probability in the same way as I did for $A$, using the same fixed thresholds (30 and 0.3)

1. with frequency counting
2. via copula

Once I have the probabilities in both datasets $P_A$ (for the dataset $A$) and $P_B$ (for the dataset $B$), I am interested in compare them, if the probabilities are significantly different. For the frequency counting, I considered to apply  z-test or t-test, but I am not sure if there is another test more appropriate. And, any idea about how to compare the probabilities obtained with the copula model?

Comment: The answer depends on what you assume about the joint distribution of $(x,y)$; about the relationships between the subsets (for instance, are they necessarily disjoint?); and about how you might be estimating the copula.  Please provide those details in an edit to your post.

Comment: Thank you for the edits, but they are very confusing.  Are you assuming the *variables* are independent or the *subsets* are?  Your language is ambiguous; it suggests you mean the subsets, but then what are "independent subsets"??  What does it mean to subscript a probability with a subset?  In what sense are 120 and 30 "the same threshold"?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, just edited the question. Hope it's clearer now, thanks!

Comment: Thanks--the question is sufficiently clear now.  But to get decent answers about the copula, I think you'll need to explain *how* you fit the copula.  And to get anything that's better than the usual tests of proportions, you likely will need to exploit your time series model, so it could help to explain what that is.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm fitting the copula with the data, e.g. fitCopula(tCopula(), pobs(data), method = 'ml'). So, you mean I would need to work with the simulated data from my copula? or what exactly do you suggest? I am not sure what you suggest, I am bit confused here... thanks!